# error "<file-name> already exists with <field/value...> (132)"

Tags: sql, runtime-error, openedge

I work in a medical laboratory, where we use an progress database (version 10.2B) and a 4GL programmed commercial application as our central laboratory information system.

We are currently developing different sentinel applications (for example lab guide) which interact with the progress database using an ODBC connection (SQL based). The applications are programmed using C#.

This interaction works fine for reading and updating records.. however, when inserting new records in an existing table, there seems to be a conflict between the sentinel and central application. Inserting a new record via the sentinel application gives no error, but when I insert a new record subsequently via the central system, the following error occurs:  already exists with  132.

It seems that the commercial 4GL based application does not see that a new record has been added to the database via SQL ODBC connection. How can I prevent this error from occuring? Keeping in mind that I have no access to the commercial 4GL system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is telling you the record already exists, not that it can't find it.

You're not "playing nice" with the application which no-doubt has it's own way of populating the various tables. You need to talk to the app vendor to see what the app expects, or have them develop an import routine to bring in your data in a way that's friendly to the app.

Comment: It is highly likely that the app uses sequences or sequence style tables to keep track of the next ID numbers. If you are just finding the MAX current value for your insert and not updating those sequence values then you will run into problems (like your error).

Comment: Specifically it is very likely that the 4gl app is using a create trigger to populate the id field.  SQL clients are unaware of and do not fire 4gl triggers.  Thus any logic that the app has built in via 4gl triggers to maintain table relationships and so forth will not be honored by the SQL app.

Comment: You're both missing what the OP wrote as opposed what he's diagnosed the problem is. The SQL program is adding the record, and it's sticking. The _application_ is the one complaining it's trying to _add_ a record and the record it's trying to add _is already there_  which means it's tryuing to add a new record with the same keys as what the SQL program added. If that violates a unique index, then the "132" error is the expected and understandable result.

Comment: That is what I was saying though :-) They are grabbing the next available number(key) with SQL and inserting a record. The 4GL comes along and tries to reuse that number because the lookup table/etc was not incremented by SQL.

Comment: Or, there's a "Test #" that goes with each capture, and a header/child relationship between two tables. If the test # is unique on the parent table, and the system thought it "wasn't there", then you'd see the same problem when the app tried to create a "new" parent record for that test #.

Comment: thanks for the replies.. I found today a sequence table and a built-in function to resync the numbers. When I perform a manual resync before adding something with the central application, NO ERROR IS GENERATED!! YEAH. However, now I have to found out how to manipulate  this table and how it is structured. Thanks again for the advice.

Comment: Do some playing around with the code that impacts that table and make sure you've got the same behavior as the app, and you should be good!

Comment: Update on my problem: the sequence table was a hoax (it was just there fore keeping the sequence of certain number generations, not for keeping the id's of all tables). The solution was changing the syntax: when using the SQLcommand NEXTVAL in the code of the sentinel program (instead of MAX value + 1), the central program did not give an error!